# Keras/ Tensorflow - Deploying a model (categorization and normalization)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I came to the point where I deployed my trained model done with Keras and based on Tensorflow. I have Tensorflow-Serving running and when I feed the input with the test data I get exactly the output as expected. Wonderful!

However, in the real world (deployed scenario) I need to pass a new data set to the model that the model has never seen before. And in the training/testing setup I did categorization and one-hot encoding. So I need to transform the submitted data-set first. This I might be able to do.

I also did normalization (Standardscaler from sklearn) and now I have no clue what is best practice to do here. In order to do normalization I would need to run through the training data again plus the one submitted data-set.

I believe this can be solved in an elegant way. Any ideas?

Comment: Guesswork: Export the Attributes of the Standardscaler and assign them later? Like .mean_ .scale_ .var_?

Comment: What I usually do is to pickle the fitted scaler. Then you can load it and use `scaler.transform` only on the new data.

Comment: @spadarian I see, so basically save the attributes and restore them later, right? How do you do for the categorization (e.g. a field with 3 text values that was transformed into 0,1,2)?

Comment: Well, you can a dictionary like `{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2}` and use it later to transform the new data.